# 403 Access Error returned from Browser possibly caused by AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify, isomorphic-javascript

I have my serverless web app hosted on AWS amplify. I am getting Access Denied error XML if I try refreshing the page. When I look into the Console, it shows no output. The code works fine on `localhost`, but will cause 403 error on live.

I have found a [question that is very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497969/cloudfront-returns-403-forbidden-when-refreshing-page), except I did not use CloudFront.

[image]

How can I find a potential cause of this problem?

[image]

I have tried using Digital Ocean as my web hosting service instead of AWS. The same error happens.

Comment: This error happens when the file is not publicly accessible. You have to set permission to allow Everyone read access if this is what you are trying to do.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Just a side note: adding new sections to questions is sometimes disallowed here, depending on how close the theme of the update is to the original question. I am not sufficiently _au fait_ with AWS to understand if your update is so closely related to the original question that it can't be considered to be a new question. However I note that you have two answers for your first question, and a new answer for your second, which diverges from the simple Q&A format we prefer here.

Comment: The live bounty prevents the question being closed, but it is worth bearing in mind - we want questions to live far into the future to benefit future programmers, and to serve that aim we want each question post to contain just one question.

Comment: @halfer I concur. OP is using a different host entirely in the second question, and is troubleshooting a problem found with the new host, and not with AWS.

Comment: For the googlers, a simple solution that works without leave the Amplify: [![AWS Amplify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXzH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwXzH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this by moving from AWS to Nginx for hosting.

And added this to etc/nginx/sites_available/default

```
location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
```

The reason why this is happening is because my app was a single paged app. Refreshing causes the browser to request the server, and the server does not handle requests.

Answer (score 7):

This error is coming because Amplify don't have permission to render that routes. We need to enable those.

In Your Amplify app settings go to Rewrites and redirects and add these two rules.

```
Source address                                             Target address          Type
/<*>                                                       /index.html             404 (Rewrite)
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>   /index.html       200 (Rewrite)
```

[image: Amplify 403]

Comment: If the payment server sends to a route domain/success?success=true&session_id={1321231231}. How would I handle it? 

@man.in.the.jukebox

Comment: @SulavDahal After loading the domain/success?... Call your backend API and pass the session to the API and verify the session id and show the status in UI.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon S3 will return a 403 error with a message like this for a number of reason, but the most common one that people don't expect is when the object doesn't exist. You will get this error and not a 404.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/

Comment: I would look at the network tab in your browser. It's almost certainly a 403.

Comment: 403 indeed... Thank you master

Comment: Also, it works fine on my localhost, but it doesnt work on live

Comment: Are you hosting directly on S3, or via CloudFront?

Comment: I did not use CloudFront, so i would have to say directly on S3.

Comment: I would check this out: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html. There are several things that you have to be sure to do when hosting in an S3 bucket.

Comment: Thanks, i'll take a look at it. It was working just fine 2 days ago. But started happening after i changed something in my code.

Comment: Im not using a static website. Is this still applicable?

Comment: If you aren't using a static website then what is in S3? S3 only handles static content.

Comment: i use s3 as a way to store photos... All I did was use AWS amplify to compile and run the code for my website. I think Amp stores my files on s3.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to understand the problem (what error are you getting, what is your setup, what do you mean by 'calling it directly'?).

That said, my assumption is you are hosting a Single Page Application on NginX. You have set the default page to index.html so when you call the root path, you get served the application, but when enter the path of a route in the address bar, you are getting a 404.

If so, this is a simple problem to fix. You are calling `https://URL.com/listing/LISTING_ID` and NginX is trying to find a static resource at that location. You need to intercept the 404 response and return your index.html file instead. Your client will then hit your React router and you will get the expected page.

Add this to your NginX config:

```
error_page 404 = 200 /index.html;
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you set CORS properly on your server side? With proper CORS setting, your client JS code can access the different server from its origin.

Comment: Why would CORS cause the server to respond with 403?