# How to see requests made to origin in cloudfront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a cloudfront distribution with 2 origins and 2 behaviors:

```
/apply* -> S3 bucket
Default * -> webflow page
```

For some reason, the `/apply*` is resulting in 404s even though the s3 bucket has several routes such as `/apply` and `/apply/demographic`

Not sure why this is happening but want to debug this by seeing where the requests are actually going to on the s3 bucket. Is there a way to see this?

Comment: Are you hosting a React app in S3?

Comment: @Anton yes I am - using react-router-dom

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution to your problem. It's the approach that I'm using myself.

Answer (score 0):

[CloudFront logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/AccessLogs.html) and especially [S3 access logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html) will give you what you want.

However, unless you added some custom logic like Lambda@Edge, the requests routing is usually quite straightforward - if your URL is `example.com/apply` CloudFront will look for a file called `apply` in the root of the bucket.

##### Solution for a React app

You mentioned that you are hosting a React app. To make React router work when hosted on S3/CloudFront it's common to override 403 and 404 errors with 200 OK status code and redirect the requests to `index.html`. In the CloudFront distribution go to *Error pages* and add two overrides:

```
403 -> 200 /index.html
404 -> 200 /index.html
```

[image]

Also, see a related SO question - [Cloudfront returns 403 forbidden when refreshing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46497969/cloudfront-returns-403-forbidden-when-refreshing-page).

Comment: I think this would work if example.com/index.html pointed to my s3 bucket but keep in mind that I have behaviors in CloudFront such that only /apply* goes to the s3 bucket. Thus, rerouting to /index.html actually goes to my webflow page. Does that make sense?